# Xcode PopOver - Cross file function use?

Tags: xcode, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have a UIPopoverController in my project.

File composition

Mainfile.h
Mainfile.m
Mainfile.xib (VIEW)

tableview.h
tableview.m
tableview.xib (TABLE VIEW)

i put my method for my PopoverController in my mainfile. My problem is i cannot access my method from mainfile.m to tableview.m when i select a row in a table.

My code

Mainfile.h

```
UIPopoverController *popMenu;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPopoverController *popMenu;
-(IBAction)showPopOverid) sender;
-(IBAction)hidePopOver;
```

Mainfile.m

```
#import "tableview.h"

-(IBAction)showPopOverid) sender {

if ([popMenu isPopoverVisible]) {
[popMenu dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {

tableview *toc = [[tocView alloc] init];
popMenu = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:toc];
[toc release];
[popMenu presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAn y animated:YES];

}

}

-(IBAction)hidePopOver {
NSLog(@"hidePopOver");
[popMenu dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

in other file

tableview.m

```
- (void)tableViewUITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPathNSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//I WANT TO ACCESS THE METHOD of hidePopOver from the mainfile so i can hide my popViewController
// i've tried a lot but not working
NSLog(@"hidePopOver"); 

}
```

Thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a `ParentViewController` and a `childViewControllerPopover` for popover on some button and a 'childViewController' on it!
For closing your `childViewControllerPopover` you can use such a blow code

First in `ChildViewController.h`

```
@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate
    -(void)closeView;
@end

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController{
    id<ChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

When one `cell` of `yourTable` selected! you should call that method, so put this in `ChildViewController.m`

```
- (void)tableViewUITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPathNSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    [delegate closeView];
}
```

And in your `ParnetViewController.h`

```
@interface ParnetViewController : UIViewController <ChildViewControllerDelegate>{
    UIPopoverController *childViewControllerPopover;
}
```

And for `ParnetViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ChildViewController *childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
    childViewController.delegate = self;
    childViewControllerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:childViewController];
    [childViewController release];
}

-(void)closeView{
    [childViewControllerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    // Do anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use a delegate to call the other method. Xcode doesn't have a global controller that lets you call other class methods when they aren't the focus of the program.